# Load img tag source before css is applied in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, components

I want to input a picture in my Lightbox, but from what I see the problem is that the CSS is applied before the img source can be loaded inside of the tag

Problem: The Lightbox Activates without an image source.

It only works if I put an img source manually.

```js
class LightboxTest extends Component {
    state = {};

    render() {
        return (<React.Fragment>
            <div
                className={this.props.setActivity === false ? 'lightboxOff' : this.props.setActivity === true ? 'lightboxActive' : ''}
            >
                <img alt="" src={this.props.lbImages} />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>);
    }
}

export default LightboxTest;
```

I'm passing a boolean 'setActivity' per props to check whether an image has been clicked on to set the Lightbox Active and 'lbImages' as my source which should be loaded, when clicked on an image.

```js
<div className="header">
    {images.map((image) => (
        <React.Fragment key={image.id}>
            <img
                alt=""
                src={image.src}
                key={image.id}
                onClick={() => {
                    setLightboxImage(image.src);
                }}
                onClick={handleClick}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    ))}
</div>
```

When I remove the lightbox div tag the image appears with no issue when Clicked on.

Can I set like a priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two onClick handlers, so the second one isn't executed. Can be changed to:

```
onClick={() => {
  setLightboxImage(image.src);
  handleClick();
}}
```